# How do I view raw system memory of a running process?

Tags: macos, memory, filesystems

I am watching a video series where someone is changing memory of a program that is in runtime. I am trying to do the same thing but have a different operating system. He is able to locate all running processes by typing

```
/ proc
```

Then from there he is able to enter directories which contain raw memory from the processes he has running.

```
cat /proc/6024/maps
```

On OS X I know I can use the command

```
lsof
```

To view all running processes, but I am unsure how to view the memory of those processes. How do I view raw system memory of a running process?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `/proc` filesystem on OSX. You need to use tools. The tools I am thinking of is `Instruments` which is part of the XCode developer toolchain on OSX. You can do a lot of thing by instrumenting any running process. Beware that this tool is powerful and not so easy to use. Read tutorials...